Is there a guide system in Maya similar to guides in Photoshop / Illustrator?
I am new to 3D modelling and Maya, I have a background in traditional drafting and programmes like Photoshop / Illustrator etc.
In Maya I am finding myself lost looking at meshes, often I need to make a mark on a mesh, like an arbitrary vertical or horizontal line just to see if it coincides with another element or is proportional to something else etc etc.
I have not found anything in Maya that I can achieve this need with. I thought of using the pencil tool but that only draws on the viewport, so if the camera moves, its no longer useful.
One thing I tried is to draw marks like straight lines with the curve tool, then place it in a display layer and lock it via "R" or "T".

But even this becomes useless when I start to work on my actual model by entering component mode the line cannot be seen anymore.

Is there proper feature in Maya for this sort of task?
If not, I am confident I can make do with curves but is there a way in Maya to control the thickness of a specific curve and also have it be visible at all times?
I am open to solution in Mel/Python scripts too.

THis may not be the best place to ask. But maya has a really good snapping functions that work on middle mouse click. So i would just draw a first degree line with curve tool, then snap it into place. Though seems to me that you can grab the gimbal arrow in the sideways direction then middlemouse snap on the point (hold x) you wanted to check and if it moved it was not aligned, then undo. You move the line upwards and or give it more thickness, but the function is a bit hidden, i think you may need to script it. Been a 10 years since i used maya daily. Its under shape node extra attributes.

Another option is to use a very thin bone. Then you can use xray joints to show it always on top of whatever object. Change default joint color so its more visible though. But i wonder if you really just only need to toggle retain component spacing and grid/point snap (x and v)i n the end but who knows. Right now this is a XY problem

Will look into that, thanks @joojaa
